# Unique list and how many times each number occurs in the original list

Tags: c#

```
for (int i = 0; i < Getallen.Count; i++)
{
    Getal = Convert.ToInt32(Getallen[i]);
    gevonden = false;
    for (teller = 0; teller < Uniekelijst.Count; teller++)
    {
        if (Uniekelijst[teller].Equals(Getallen[i]))
        {
            gevonden = true;
        }
    }
    if (!gevonden)
    {
        Uniekelijst.Add(Getal);
        teller.Equals(Getallen);
        Console.WriteLine("unieke lijst " + Uniekelijst[teller] + " Unique list and how many times each number occurs in the original list (what do i add here to complete it?**strong text**) ");
    }
}
```

this is one of the options in a menu for a test we need to make in school our teacher want us to always ask the internet and find out ourselves but I can't find a direct answer to this

Comment: Seeking for a direct answer would not be the best approach. I suggest you use English variables to make your code more readable for others. And please provide what you tried so far. Also welcome to SO

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I'm afraid it's not clear what specifically you are asking.  Please carefully describe the problem that you are observing in your code and any attempt you have made to correct that problem.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: May you use linq or you have to realize an algorithm of filter list?